# New to WSDL's getting errors during proxy generation

Tags: c#, wsdl, svcutil.exe

The company I work for does work with outside vendors for our software.  I have been given the task of creating my first windows service to communicate with the vendors web service.  The vendor gave us a copy of their WSDL and 39 XSD files.  I convert the XSD files to class files with no problems.  However, when I try to convert the WSDL, I get the following errors:

**When using wsdl.exe**

> Error: Unable to import binding 'BasicHttpBinding_ITrakManService'
>   from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'.
>        - Unable to import operation 'AddRedactedDocument'.
>        - The element 'http://tempuri.org/:AddRedactedDocument' is missing.

**When using svcutil.exe**

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType 
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' could not be
>   found.
>
> XPath to Error Source:
>
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org']/wsdl:portType[@name='ITrakManService']
>         Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on. XPath
>   to wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='ITrakManService']
>
> XPath to Error Source:
>
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ITrakManService']
>
> Generating files... Warning: No code was generated. If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata
>   documents did not contain any valid contracts or services or because
>   all contracts/services were discovered to exist in reference
>   assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the
>   tool.

I saw a few people reference changing the imports section of the wsdl to includes, but none of the imports are referencing explicit XSD's, for reference this is the import section.

```
-<wsdl:types>
-<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" schemaLocation="http://vcp01xred-grd.clerkdev.clerk.local:8090/TrakManWebService.svc?xsd=xsd0"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" schemaLocation="http://vcp01xred-grd.clerkdev.clerk.local:8090/TrakManWebService.svc?xsd=xsd1"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TrakManBusiness" schemaLocation="http://vcp01xred-grd.clerkdev.clerk.local:8090/TrakManWebService.svc?xsd=xsd2"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" schemaLocation="http://vcp01xred-grd.clerkdev.clerk.local:8090/TrakManWebService.svc?xsd=xsd3"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question for you WSDL experts, this is my attempt at doing one.  I also have tried this with the XSD files in the same directory as the WSDL and the errors were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have been through this many times where if there are multiple xsds , wsdl to java conversions (or others fail ) . One quick-fix solution which has worked for me is , combining all the XSDs to one XSD and then writing down the WSDL , quite a painful task but might work . Imports fail when there are circular and deeper imports .